Optimal Cable Routing for Basement Kitchen Circuits
I live in Ontario Canada
How should I route the cables for three circuits in my basement kitchen? The circuits are designated for the fridge, microwave, and washing machine (which needs to go through the kitchen wall). Should I consider:

Passing all three cables through a single hole in the studs?
Creating three separate holes in the stud for each circuit?
Routing the wires through the ceiling to the laundry area instead?



Is that a built-in microwave?

Keep in mind that if this is officially a kitchen then you will need at least two 20A "countertop" circuits. If it is "not officially a kitchen, just an extra area that is sort-of kitchen-like" then you may not hit that requirement, but even then at least one extra circuit for plugging in small appliances is a good idea.

@kmj no it's not a built in microwave but it will have it's own socket and to be in a separate circuit

I asked because if it's dedicated it doesn't count toward your two small appliance 20A circuits. The fridge certainly doesn't. So it sounds like you're going to need at least two more circuits for an actual kitchen. If there's no water this might count as a kitchenette and all those rules go away, but an open 20A small appliance circuit is still a good idea.

Does Canada have the same "two 20A circuits" req as NEC?
